# How to insert image in scale 1:1

Tags: html, css, image, header

I have an image with dimension 2000x160 I have to put it as header with 1:1 scale.

I have this markup but it won't works.

```
<div id="header">
    <a href="#" style="display:block;width:100%;height:160px;"><img src="/images/header-bg.jpg" alt="header"></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/*header*/
#header {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #5f9936;
    height: 160px;
    width: 100%;
}
#header img {
    height: 160px;
}
```

Comment: Try specifying the width and height as attributes of the `<img>` tag

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dJfDS/

Comment: I'm not surprised. `width:100%` means 100% of the container, not the image itself. Try `width:2000px` instead. If necessary, do something with `overflow:hidden` to get rid of the resulting horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: but I want to keep it extends beyond the width of the header.

Comment: Why don't you use the image as the background in CSS? Remove the `img` element, and change `#header`'s `background` to `url("/images/header-bg.jpg") #5F9936`. You can then use the `background-position` (Google it) property to adjust centering.

Comment: @Kroltan it's ok i did it but how can I make it responsive with 768px and 320px?

Comment: What do you mean by responsive?

Comment: yakuzaki.webd.pl check this header when I make site smaller it dissapear. I want to not lose on quality and so as not to extend.

Comment: It doesn't disappear to me... What does happen is that the navigation buttons at the top get stacked, maybe the header got out of your view that way

Comment: Change your browser site to 400px and look at header image

Comment: Maybe you mean that the logo and certificate-like-thing are not onscreen? If you need them at all times, you'd better make them separate images and put as elements inside the header.

Comment: Is there any other solution? Because I got ready graphics.

Comment: Either that, or stretch the whole header background image. It would look REALLY ugly, though.

Comment: What do you think about make 2 pictures one large and the second smaller when browser window width is less than 480px then load small picture.

Comment: Sounds good, but you'd still run into the same issue: reducing the header height or stretching the image. Example of resizing the header with media queries: http://jsfiddle.net/dJfDS/2/

Comment: I will try option with loading two images.

Comment: Just watch for the network load! Mind if I post the result of this discussion as an answer? (It's a Q&A site, after all, and your original issue did get solved)

Comment: This discussion is growing way beyond the scope of your original question. You are probably better off with a responsive framework.

Comment: I didn't see that you post an example. It's good I think I could use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a CSS background instead of a `<img>`, and use `background-position` to make it centered.
Also, addressing your visibility issue on low resolutions, you can use media queries to resize the background image (or even apply a different background image with lower resolution).

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dJfDS/2/

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: url("http://www.placehold.it/2000x160") #5f9936;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    height: 160px;
    width: 100%;
}
@media all and (max-width: 900px) {
    #header {
        height: 80px;
    }
}
#header a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```